# Adjust size of geoms when zooming in `ggiraph`

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggiraph

The `ggiraph` package extends `ggplot2` to add interactivity. One feature is the ability to zoom in on a plot, for example using the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggiraph)

data(mtcars)

mtcars$model <- rownames(mtcars)

gg <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = disp)) +
  geom_point_interactive(aes(color = as.factor(cyl),
                             tooltip = model))

girafe(ggobj = gg) %>%
    girafe_options(opts_zoom(max = 5),
                   opts_tooltip(use_fill = TRUE))
```

When previewing the chart is is possible to zoom in by clicking the magnifying glass and scrolling. As the user zooms, the points enlarge, but the tooltip stays the same size.

**Is it possible to adjust the geom sizes (e.g., point radius or line thickness) when zooming in?**

There are probably lots of reasons this would be useful, but I'm specifically thinking about overplotting - I have a dense dataset but zooming in doesn't help because the points still cover one another.

I'm using `ggiraph` because it is a simple extension to `ggplot2` but if there is a comparable package I would be open to other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Your code is not reproducible as `model` is not available so I assume that you have assigned the row names of `mtcars` to the vector `model`.

I don't think that You can do this in `ggiraph` but it's straightforward in `plotly`: You may generate a `ggplot` object and simply convert it to a `plotly` object using `plotly::ggplotly()`.

For the `mtcars` example in Your question, the following does the trick:

```
library(plotly)

data(mtcars)

# generate ggplot object
gg <- ggplot(mtcars) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = mpg, y = disp, col  = as.factor(cyl), text = rownames(mtcars))) 

# convert to plotly object
ggplotly(gg, tooltip = "text")
```

The result looks like a `ggplot2` but is interactive and does not suffer from the zooming issue. You may play with it in the viewer, include it in output formats that support HTML widgets or view it in the browser.

[image]

As the above is just sceenshot I uploaded the output to my account on plot.ly. You can find it [here](https://plot.ly/~Emwikts1970/93/#/) and play around with it.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! You're right about the assumption for `model`. I'll update the example.